# Removing Batch Effect in Heatmaps after Differential Gene Expression Analysis

Tags: rna-seq, edger, limma, heatmap, batch-effects

I'm working on a dataset in which the first replicate of each group is one batch and the second replicate is in a second batch. After checking the `PCA` plot and seeing the batch effect in PC1, I used `removeBatchEffect` function from limma to subtract the batch effect from my count data. Then, using PCA gives me a plot that doesn't seem to have any apparent batch effect left! However, it is recommended not to use batch effect correction for differential gene analysis but use the batch variable along with the group variable in constructing the `model.matrix`. So, I did that, ran `limma/voom` on the normalized counts, and extracted differentially expressed genes. However, when I'm trying to make a heatmap from the DEGs, I still see that the samples from different batches are clustered separately, instead of seeing the clustering of replicates of the same sample. So, my question is whether I should use `removeBatchEffect` on the count data from DEGs and then use the transformed dataset for heatmaps or there is another way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you could try more state-of-the-art of methods like "comBat" from "sva" package to remove the batch effects.

Comment: I read a few posts in biostar that confirmed my choice of `removeBatchEffect` from `limma` over `comBat` from `sva`. The gist of it was that we should not use tools like `comBat` because they are biased towards removing all batch effects. Moreover, `comBat` and also `removeBatchEffect` generate negative sign results which can't be processed by voom or edgeR and trying to remove these negative results is another level of manipulation in the dataset. So, it is better to use `removeBatchEffect` for visualizations but just use batch in `model.matrix` for differential gene expression analysis

Comment: Read [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/266507/) for more information.

Comment: It is true that comBat introduces negative values. This is because comBat should be used on a normalized matrix. If all values in the matrix is positive, I am assuming it is a count matrix (which a newer version of sva takes care of) or a TPM matrix (which should be normalized first.) I think maybe you could run comBat after voom if you decide to use that. But of course using limma in a right way could work as well.

Comment: Could you please clarify your comment a bit. my data is already log2 scaled, filtered for lowly expressed genes and also TMM normalized, but I still get negative values with `comBat` and also `removeBatchEffect`. However, I'm using batch as a covariat in my model.matrix and do the DEG analysis. You meant I can use comBat on DEGs for visualizations?

Comment: If your data is log2 scaled, are there negative values before removing any batch effects?

Comment: I just checked and `Yes` there are a few negative values before removing batch effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed true that for the DE analysis one should include batch into the formula to avoid changing the original counts. Still, for everything else such as plotting heatmaps use of `removeBatchEffects` is perfectly fine and (at least to me) a standard and well-accepted procedure. It essentially does not matter what you use to correct for the batch effect for the counts you use downstream. Results will probably be similar. `Combat-Seq` from the sva package is a recent adaptation of ComBat specifically for RNA-seq which (from what I understand) better deals with the integer-count nature of the data. This operates on raw counts and avoids the infamous negative values that happen at times with both `limma` and `Combat`. After applying `ComBat-Seq` on your raw counts you can normalize them as usual with edgeR (or any tool you like) and then make the heatmaps. See https://github.com/zhangyuqing/ComBat-seq. The DE results still should come from the normal DE pipeline with batch as covariate as discussed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one confusing thing about it. I first normalize, filter, and log2 scale and then do the EdgeR analysis with batch as covariat. Then, should I use the normalized.filtered.log2 as the output for `ComBat-seq` for module identification using heatmaps or should I just select differentially expressed genes from my raw data and use that as input for heatmaps and clustering?

Comment: Or maybe it is better to first use `ComBat-seq` and eliminate the batch effect and then go through my normal workflow? Is this your recommended approach?

Comment: I just checked `combat-seq` on my raw data and then did the normalization steps and compared its PCA plot with the corresponding plot for `comBat`. It not only didn't improve the distance between replicates but, not significantly, `comBat` seems to perform better!!

Comment: As I said above, do your standard edgeR analysis with batch as covariate to get DE genes. Then, as a second step to get batch-corrected counts do ComBat-Seq on the raw count matix, normalize and log2 it and use this for heatmaps (and every other downstream analysis). Without full code and plots I cannot comment on what you describe. In my hands ComBat-seq worked very well and removes batch effects effectively.

Comment: @ATpoint thanks I agree with your points. Do you think its fair to run the standard DE with the batch as covariate, but when generating the post analysis plot, to merge the corrected dataframe ( say in log cpm) back with the statistical output for plotting?